# is there a way to create a user defined function like this

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to TSQL and am trying to create a function that would calculate Longitude and give a radius. I know how to do it in C# but now having difficulty translating it into T-SQL this is the multi-part function

```
   1. double Long = (Math.Cos((double)2.55 * (Math.PI / 180)) * 69);
   2. double milesss = 10 / Long;
   3.  item.TenLonMin = Math.Round(((double)item.longitudes - milesss), 6);
```

The answer to all of this is step 3 and I would like to put that inside this

```
UPDATE zips
SET 
 TwoLonMax= answer to step 3 here
```

How can I go about doing this? I have bee trying to find out how I can plug in the results of user defined functions.

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) for creating a scalar function? Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. I assume you're using some version of SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry about that will read it right now and yes it is MYSQL 2012. I am very new to this and didn't think there was a big difference in TSQL between versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it in T-SQL but its performance will be poor, comparing with C#, C++ and most programming languages:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_ITEM_TENLONMIN(@LONGITUDES FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @LONG FLOAT;
SET @LONG=COS(2.55 * (PI() / 180)) * 69;
DECLARE @MILESSS FLOAT;
SET @MILESSS = 10 / @LONG;
RETURN @LONGITUDES - @MILESSS;
END;
```

I just used your own calculation method.

Comment: It is look like you are trying to reinvented the wheel! SQL Server include Spatial Data Types like geography data types, and already include all the functions to calculate and work with this type like calculate Longitude. Check this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964711.aspx